# Steps to execute Oracle sql scripts using Ant build file

Tags: database, oracle, ant

I am new to learning ant. I have an exercise to automate oracle scrips execution using Ant. Can you please share steps/sample code on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ANT#SQL Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html) to execute your scripts.

for example below sql task will execute `example.sql`:

```
<sql
     driver="${dbdrv}"
     url="${dburl}"
     userid="${dbusr}"
     password="${dbpwd}"
     src="example.sql"
     classpath="${cp}"
   />
```